# Columnwise line numbering in a two column environment (with multicol)

Tags: multicol, line-numbering, lineno

In a two column environment, I need

- columnwise line numbering and
- the possibility to get the actual column number.

Now, columnwise line numbering is possible with `lineno` and the option `columnwise`.

And I can get the actual column number in a `multicols` environment, using `multicol` with the option `colaction` and the command `\docolaction`.

But unfortunately, columnwise line numbering seems not to work in the `multicols` environment. So how can I achieve what I want?

(Actually, I want to create references to columns, but I would already be happy if I could just get the actual column number.)

You may consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,DIV=14]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage[columnwise,modulo]{lineno} 

\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}

\newcommand\showcolumn{%
\docolaction{1}{}{2}%
}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\newcommand\Test{THIS IS COLUMN \showcolumn{}. }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%% \twocolumn
\begin{multicols}{2}
\linenumbers

\lipsum*[1]
\Test
\lipsum*[1-2]
\Test
\lipsum*[1]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

In the result, line numbering is not columnwise. When removing the multicols environment and using the `\twocolumn` command instead, line numbering is columnwise, but then I cannot use `\docolaction`. So what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Columnwise numbering in `lineno` is incompatible with `multicol`. The problem is that `lineno` attaches its numbers to each line as they are generated, and then `multicol` takes all those lines and puts them into columns when the page is being output. So at the time the line numbers are generated, neither `lineno` nor `multicol` can know which column a line will wind up in.

If you use twocolumn mode, you can figure out which column you're in by checking the x value at the point you're referencing. Since it seems like your end goal is to create a column/line reference, I hacked up a simple solution using `zref-savepos` that produces a reference in the form [column].[line]. It simply assumes that if we're on the left half of the page we're in the first column and otherwise in the second, but it should be easy to adapt to your specific needs. It will require at least two runs to get the correct value.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,fontsize=12pt,DIV=14]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[columnwise,modulo]{lineno} 
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\newlength{\midpage}
\setlength{\midpage}{.5\paperwidth}
\newcommand\labelcolumnline[1]{%
  \zsavepos{#1}%
  \linelabel{#1}%
}

\newcommand\refcolumnline[1]{%
  \ifnum\number\zposx{#1}>\number\midpage\relax 2\else 1\fi%
  .\ref{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

\lipsum*[1]\labelcolumnline{r1}

\lipsum*[1-2]\labelcolumnline{r2}

\lipsum*[1]

The first paragraph ends at \refcolumnline{r1}.

The third paragraph ends at \refcolumnline{r2}.
\end{document}
```

[image]